# Monitoring text property validity as user types

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, textbox

[Winforms Application .NET 4.0 C#]

I have a textbox that receives data from a handheld barcode scanner.

I want my application to check if the text is valid without the user having to do anything.

Example rule:

- Text length =18 and starts with '1520'
- Text length =17 and starts with '0520'

Should i checkit with:

- TextChanged event?
- Add a timer to check the rules every 200-300ms?

something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextChanged` event will suffice, I have implemented something similar in the past and you will only be notified once so you will have the full barcode on each scan.

Comment: Normally only once , but on manual entry by the user it will fire the event in any case, yes?

Comment: @e4rthdog sorry, yes it will trigger each time the user inputs text. I was purely focused on the fact your question reads "*I have a textbox that receives data from a handheld barcode scanner*". What you could do is have a timer which starts on the `TextChanged` event and give it a reasonable length of time before it triggers your lookup code e.g. 1 second. You would then cancel the timer & reset it every time new input is entered. Alternatively, you could have your application switch into different modes e.g. scanner/manual input mode (which is what I did with my app).